# How to build an airport at 30,000ft?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, physics, atmosphere, flight

What differences might an airport runway and landing differences have on Mount Everest for airplanes at 30,000ft? The drawn line in the pictures is about 2 miles. This would be practical for hand gliding, skiing, base jumping, shortcut to the top, and other exotic fun.

[image][image]

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please note that you are asking 3 different questions: how to build it, what differences would it have w.r.t. to a conventional one and the fuel saving. As stated in our [help], we answer 1 world building question per post.

Comment: Winds and icing alone would kill more planes (and crews and passengers) than they'd get off the ground safely.  A nightmare location.

Comment: Also lookup "Death Zone" on wikipedia. Theres no skiing or hang gliding up here. You need supplemental oxygen to survive outside.

Comment: To expand on L.Dutch's comment, if you can edit your question into a simplified version only asking one question, it can be reopened.

Comment: You really need to do a little background reading in practical aviation, and particularly the concept of density altitude.  Basically, the thinner the air (which depends on both altitude & temperature), the faster you need to be going to fly, and the lower your rate of climb will be once you get off the ground.  Every summer, a few sea level pilots learn that lesson the hard way when trying to take off from local fields that are at 6000 ft/2000 m or more.

Comment: @jamesqf I am working on my BS in aeronautics.

Comment: What are you going to build it *with*? Are you shipping materials and heavy construction equipment all the way up the mountain?

Comment: @Cadence That is what I wonder.

Comment: @Justintimeforfun: Then you should be familiar with density altitude, and how to calculate required runway, rates of climb, and so on.  For others, here's a link to a brief explanation: https://americanflyers.com/dog-days-of-summer/

Comment: And how are you supposed to use the runway?  I was trying to figure how if your stall speed was above your max rolling velocity and stumbled on the fact that the 737 has a max airport altitude of 8,400', 12,000' with a high altitude option.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Yes, standard planes could not land there, and a special landing gear would have to be installed. I'm going on the bases if a plane can fly at 40,000 feet then maybe it can land at a lower altitude. Maybe only small jets can land there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Glider port.**

[image: perian glider]

https://www.airbus.com/newsroom/stories/airbus-perlan-mission-ii.html

> At 90,000 feet, the Perlan 2 must be engineered to fly in less than 3%
> of normal air density and at temperatures of -70°C. The mission will
> harvest invaluable data for scientists worldwide to help update and
> improve existing climate models.

30,000 feet is just an appetizer for this awesome glider.  The gliders will start at low alititude being towed by planes, then coast upwards as gliders do.  They are not fast moving craft and landing at altitude should poise no particular difficulty.  Ideally the landing strip is over a cliff, so on returning the glider can just fall over the edge of clif and glide away.

Comment: Great answer!!!

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

30,000 feet is above the service ceiling of most aircraft: helicopters tend to top out around 10,000-15,000 feet, piston-engine aircraft are usually limited to 25,000 or so, and even turboprops rarely venture that high.  The only aircraft that could theoretically operate out of your airport are turbofan-powered jets.

So let's say you wanted to land a Boeing 737 at your high-altitude airport: how fast would it be going?  Boeing doesn't publish performance charts for altitudes that high, but we can estimate based on known performance.

There's a useful measurement called "calibrated air speed": it's a measure of how much air is moving past the airplane, so it's independent of things like altitude and temperature.  The target landing CAS of a 737 is roughly 150 knots, and we can use standard correction formulas to figure out what the true speed is at 30,000 feet and average temperatures.  Turns out, in order to land in calm air, your 737 is going slightly over 240 knots across the ground -- a bit faster than the wheels are rated for.

Comment: Boeing says 8,400' for standard, 12,000' with a high altitude option for the 737.